# Where are Flow type definitions in VSCode?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I created a new React Native project with create-react-native-app and added `// @flow` at the top of a file to get proper type checks. Then I added a basic component:

```js
export class Foo extends React.component {
  render() {
    <Text>abcd</Text>
  }
}
```

You might notice the missing `return` in line 2. Since flow does not complain about it, I wanted to add a type annotation, something like:

```js
  render(): JSX.Element {
```

However, I could not figure out, how to import JSX. Thus, I jumped to the definition file of my `import React from 'react'` statement to see how it looked like. Then I suddenly noticed that the type definitions where declared in an `index.d.ts`, i.e. a Typescript definition file: [image: typescript definition for react]

Is this the usual behaviour for Flow-typed React (Native) projects? I think this would be weird, since the two languages differ. If not, how do I make VSCode use Flow definitions instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming:

- Your `Foo` component has a `.js` extension
- VSCode didn't bark about types only being allowed in `.ts` files when you added the return type `: JSX.Element`.

This would suggest that VSCode is set up to use Flow instead of Typescript.  Meaning your error looks something like this:

[image]

I'm using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=flowtype.flow-for-vscode).

Assuming this is true, you can import the JSX namespace like so:

```
import JSX from 'react';
```

Which will emit the following compiler warning if you forget your `return` statement:

[image]

Note that you need a type parameter on `JSX.Element`.  The compiler will accept `JSX.Element<any>` or even `JSX.Element<>`, but not `JSX.Element`.